# Portable pull tool compatible with GitHub

Tags: gratis, git, version-control, portable, github

When working on a GitHub repo, GitHub offers their GitHub Desktop as well as their web-app.  Unfortunately, their web-app has many [limitations and quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215513/is-it-possible-to-paste-more-than-one-line-into-github).

Often it is not desirable or feasible to install the full GitHub Desktop.  Are there portable Windows-compatible tools to perform pull operations on GitHub repo's?